# $type property automatically generated when migrated to cosmos db SDK v3 .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

Kinda new to the .NET and have the task of migrating cosmos db v2 sdk to v3.

I have noticed when using V3 sdk of .NET, every document created or updated has this default property of `$type`. Example below.

I am not sure what is that property? Is there a way to remove it?

After in v3 sdk:

```
"DataSample1": {
    "0": 1,
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib"
}
```

Before in v2 sdk:

```
"DataSample1": {
    "0": 1
},
```

If anyone could help me understand what is that **"$type"** property in each document I create.

Here is the base document class.

```
public class BaseCosmosDBDocument : Document
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseCosmosDBDocument"/> class.
        /// Keep default constructor here, preventing from cosmos document deserializing failure
        /// </summary>
        public BaseCosmosDBDocument()
            : base()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BaseCosmosDBDocument"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="createdDateTime">created date time of document</param>
        [JsonConstructor]
        public BaseCosmosDBDocument(DateTimeOffset createdDateTime)
            : base()
        {
            this.CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets created Date Time
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CreatedDateTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes this base class CosmosDB document to the specified subclass type.
        /// Note: Property bag should be initialized with subclass values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type this base update policy should deserialize to</typeparam>
        /// <returns>This update policy deserialized to the subclass type</returns>
        public T ReadAsDocumentSubclass<T>() where T : BaseCosmosDBDocument
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                this.SaveTo(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Were you passing a custom JsonSerializerSettings to the DocumentClient (V2) or the operations?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta yes I have custom Json serializer for base document.
added base document classs in question.